# function won't run in unityscript

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript, unity3d-2dtools

I new to  unityscript and am making a platformer game in Unity 2D but my character Movement script won't work. I assume that the function isn't being called but it used to work.

this is the code:

```
#pragma strict

var JumpSpeed : float = 10;
var walkSpeed : float = 10;
var gravity : float = 50;



function update () {
    var Controller : CharacterController = GetComponent(CharacterController);
    var vertical : Vector2 = transform.TransformDirection(Vector2.up);
    var jump : Vector2 = transform.TransformDirection(Vector2.zero);

    if(Input.GetAxis("Vertical") || Input.GetAxis("Jump")){
        Controller.Move((vertical * (walkSpeed * Input.GetAxis("Vertical"))) * Time.deltaTime);
        Controller.Move((jump * (walkSpeed * Input.GetAxis("Jump"))) * Time.deltaTime);
    }
}
```

this code has no syntax errors.

Comment: "*it used to work*" - so what did you change?

Comment: There are syntax errors in the code, all of the variable declarations are incorrect - did you intend this to be a Javascript question?

Comment: How exactly is this `var JumpSpeed : float = 10;` legal javascript?  or `#pragram strict` for that matter.  What language to you really intend for this to be?

Comment: @jfriend00 it's not javascript, it's [unityscript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unityscript)

Comment: @undone - the OP tagged is as javascript so thus my comment and the title still refers to javascript.  I guess you changed the tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to use U not u to using Unity3D's update method. update -> [Update](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.Update.html)

```
function Update () {
    var Controller : CharacterController = GetComponent(CharacterController);
    var vertical : Vector2 = transform.TransformDirection(Vector2.up);
    var jump : Vector2 = transform.TransformDirection(Vector2.zero);

    if(Input.GetAxis("Vertical") || Input.GetAxis("Jump")){
        Controller.Move((vertical * (walkSpeed * Input.GetAxis("Vertical"))) * Time.deltaTime);
        Controller.Move((jump * (walkSpeed * Input.GetAxis("Jump"))) * Time.deltaTime);
    }
}
```